# Webcam poor quality on Ubuntu 18.04 using my Dell XPS 15 9500

Tags: drivers, dell, webcam

I have bought a Dell XPS 15 9500 and just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on it. I originally tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 but I was having many problems getting that to boot.

Things are now mostly okay. However I notice that my webcam is very poor quality (pixelated, patchy coloring). I imagine that it is an issue with the drivers. Hopefully it is something that I can fix but I'm not sure where to start.

Any help is appreciated.